# how to create Variable registry path in vb script

Tags: vbscript

I want help to create a registry path which will use a variable for logged in user SID. The path is like - `HKEY_USERS\'%UserSID%'\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook`

User SID should be picked for whoever user is currently logged in on the system.

I don't know how to create this variable?

I want to use this variable in my script array.

```
KEY_PATHS = Array("HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-4054882774-118064744-2143271696-500\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook", _
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-2660683129-3636505375-3381148637-65620")

DEBUG_PRINTING = False 

MASTER_EXECUTION 

Sub MASTER_EXECUTION()
    ' WMI Class Management
    MAINTAIN_WMI_CLASS()

    ' Registry Key Storage
    For Each KEY_PATH In KEY_PATHS
        STORE_KEYS(KEY_PATH)
    Next

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        EVENT_WRITER "ERROR","Storing Registry Keys Failed " & Err.Number & " | " & Err.Description
    Else
        EVENT_WRITER "INFO", "Storing Registry Keys Completed Successfully"                    
    End If
End Sub

Function CONVERT_HIVE(HIVE)
    ' Check and return a system name based on a friendly name
    If UCase(HIVE) = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" Then
        CONVERT_HIVE = &H80000002
    ElseIf UCase(HIVE) = "HKEY_USERS" Then
        CONVERT_HIVE = &H80000002
    ElseIf UCase(HIVE) = "HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG" Then
        CONVERT_HIVE = &H80000005
    Else
        EVENT_WRITER "ERROR","Converting Hive " & HIVE & " failed - " & Err.Number & " | " & Err.Description
        WScript.Quit
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] (and format it properly). Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). _Please avoid headlong changing `HKEY_USERS\<UserSID>` registry key. This hive is loaded only for a currently logged user. Pay your attention to its  exact copy at 
 `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`_.

Answer (score -1):

### I got my answer in one of Microsoft thread:

Below VB code will fetch logged in user sid and and we can use that variable for our purpose:

[vbs code in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edBFm.png)
'And the variable path i was looking for will be like

KEY_PATHS = Array("HKEY_USERS\" & Sid & "\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\PST")